# Jquery: find '.myclass' which has a parent div with class '.active'

Tags: jquery

As I am typing this question, SO is making suggestions but I couldnT find anything that is quite like my problem.. If it s a dupe of smth, sorry in advance.

Basically,

```
 <li role="presentation" class="active"><a class="graph-switch" href="#basari" data-metric="accuracy">BASARI</a></li>
 <li role="presentation"><a href="#doygunluk" class="graph-switch" data-metric="readiness">DOYGUNLUK</a></li>
 <li role="presentation"><a href="#deneyim" class="graph-switch" data-metric="experience">DENEYIM</a></li>
```

I have these `li` s. The first one is the **active** one, I want to get the `data-metric="accuracy"`

I m trying things like:

```
var metric = $(".graph-switch").parents('.active').first().data('metric');
```

but it s wrong and i know it s ugly.. There has to be a better way..
Any ideas?

Comment: Couldn't you just use `$('li.active a.graph-switch').data('metric')`?

Comment: i would if i knew ;) .. and it turns out... i can. bingo. good answer! Thanks @j08691

Comment: OK, added it as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use:

```
$('li.active a.graph-switch').data('metric')
```